# Should I learn swing to make GUI or I should simply use any IDE

Tags: java, swing

I want to know that what would help me in the long run like what the industry's trend is?
Does everyone uses GUI builder, or is it like that java isnt popularly used for GUI and acts mostly as a background operations language? 
please guide me..

Comment: Why dont you go for JavaFX 2.x it has more features than swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IDE` may not be enough for designing everything (but it helps lot in development), its always better to learn API and IDE both together.

Answer (score 3):

I would learn Swing, because it is useful to know the general ideas of how it works. As for actually generating GUIs, I would use and IDE builder because it's faster. You may find that it's useful to know how to manually fix up the generated code, so knowing Swing would be useful. Often you want to customize how part of the GUI works, and you would have to use the language directly to do that. The IDE builder can be a useful tool for quickly building *most* of the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a comment, I am no expert.
My Recommendation for Java is to learn how to do in swing manually.
However I am recently using the Windows Builder Pro that is included in the latest Eclipse Juno. And it creates the code, so you can go back to direct coding without compromise.
There must be better out there, but for my small and simple apps saves me time.
https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/userinterface/
It is included in Juno just right click a JFrame type class and select Edit with Windows Builder.
You may use the IDE tool, create the code then see it and enhance or add as you like. But for a starter you can add a Full menu, buttons and several controls in no time while maintaining a single .java file.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you learn swing because GUI builders functionality is limited. But it is ok to use GUI builder if you are developing simple apps. I prefer coding my own UI

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely go for Swing. Using an IDE may seem easy in the beginning but you have to remember that it is way too restrictive. And if you do end up learning swing you can take the thing to the next level, if you know what I mean. It also depends on whether you like to write code or not because if you don't then naturally swing will not interest you. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) a tutorial. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be a professional you'll need to master Swing along with all its nuances such as the LookAndFeel and Layouts.  `NullLayout` was my favorite layout of choice while getting started, but you'll definitely need to learn `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` as well.  Mastering the behavior and listener models will require work, but are a must for any mid-level and beyond GUI programmer.

The IDE builders are good for getting it started, but I would be leery of trusting the code that they generate, especially if you have to be personally accountable for it.  Even if you must use an IDE WSIWYG you'd better make sure you know what its doing.